# AppcompatDelegate getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

My activity should inherit from another activity(another library that I don't have access to) and I need to integrate ActionBar + Fragments inside my new Activity. I have integrated the actionbar with success using `AppCompatDelegate`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //the installViewFactory method replaces the default widgets
    //with the AppCompat-tinted versions
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getDelegate().setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getDelegate().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}

private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
    if (mDelegate == null) {
        mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
    }
    return mDelegate;
}
```

The question is how to use Fragments in this activity that extends from `android.app.Activity`?

Note: It is not a `FragmentActivity`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If android.app.Activity is your only real superclass to work with, I imagine you'll have to use the platform fragments (subclasses of android.app.Fragment) and not the compat library fragments, and it will only work with API 11 and later, when they were introduced.  [getFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager%28%29) is your entrypoint to that.

Comment: Thanks Doug, This is the backup solution that I will not be willing to implement. The appcompat has many other features like views tinting and a lot others. I can't see any other solutions  though :(